# Sum of successive powers of digits

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematics

Some numbers have funny properties. For example:

$$\eqalign{89 &→ 8^1 + 9^2 &= 89 &= 89 × 1 \\ 695 &→ 6^2 + 9^3 + 5^4 &= 1390 &= 695 × 2 \\ 46288 &→ 4^3 + 6^4 + 2^5 + 8^6 + 8^7 &= 2360688 &= 46288 × 51}$$

Given a positive integer \$n\$ written in decimal as \$abcd\dotso\$, and a positive integer \$p\$, we want to find a positive integer \$k\$, if it exists, such that the sum of the digits of \$n\$ taken to the successive powers \$p\$, \$p+1\$, \$p+2\$, …, is equal to \$nk\$. In other words:

> Is there an integer \$k\$ such that \$ a^p + b^{p+1} + c^{p+2} + d^{p+3} + \dotsb = nk\$?

If it is the case we will return \$k\$, if not return \$-1\$.

Note: \$n\$, \$p\$ will always be given as strictly positive integers.

- `dig_pow(89, 1)` should return \$1\$ since \$8^1 + 9^2 = 89 = 89 × 1\$.
- `dig_pow(92, 1)` should return \$-1\$ since there is no \$k\$ such that \$9^1 + 2^2\$ equals \$92k\$
- `dig_pow(695, 2)` should return \$2\$ since \$6^2 + 9^3 + 5^4 = 1390 = 695 × 2\$
- `dig_pow(46288, 3)` should return \$51\$ since \$4^3 + 6^4 + 2^5 + 8^7 + 8^6 = 2360688 = 46288 × 51\$

```
import math

def dig_pow(n,p):

    ''' 
    Formula :

    (a ^ p + b ^ (p+1) + c ^(p+2) + d ^ (p+3) + ...) = n * k

    '''

    ''' calculate LHS '''
    digits, temp = [], n
    for i in range(len(str(n))):
        digits.append(temp%10)
        temp = temp / 10

    Tsum = 0
    for i in reversed(digits):
        Tsum = Tsum + math.pow(i,p)
        p = p + 1

    ''' Calculate RHS '''
    if Tsum % n == 0:
        return Tsum / n
    else:
        return -1

print dig_pow(46288, 3)
print dig_pow(89, 1)
print dig_pow(695, 2)
print dig_pow(92, 1)
```

Please feel free to suggest better/faster approaches.

Answer (score 6):

1. The name could be more meaningful. It's usually a good idea to name a function after its result, which in this case is the multiplier \$k\$, so something like `digit_power_multiplier` is needed.
2. The docstring doesn't explain the arguments to the function, or what it returns. Write it from the point of view of a user who is trying to figure out how to call it.
3. Only the first string in a function definition becomes the docstring: the others are ignored. So make them comments instead.
4. Returning exceptional values to indicate failure (here, `-1` when no \$k\$ is found) is risky: the caller might forget to check for the exceptional value. It's more reliable to raise an exception.
5. Python has an exponentiation operator `**` so there is no need to use `math.pow`.
6. When splitting `n` into its digits you use `len(str(n))` to find the number of digits. But if you're going to call `str(n)` you may as well extract the digits from the result, [as suggested by vertere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/91364/11728) in another answer.
7. The division operator `/` changed its meaning in Python 3: it's now floating-point division. To make your code portable to Python 3, use the *floor division* operator `//` when you want the integer part of the quotient.
8. When simultaneously iterating over a sequence and an index, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). So instead of:

   ```
   Tsum = 0
   for i in digits:
       Tsum = Tsum + math.pow(i,p)
       p = p + 1
   ```

   write:

   ```
   Tsum = 0
   for q, d in enumerate(digits, p):
       Tsum = Tsum + d ** q
   ```

   [Thanks to Josay in comments for improving this.]
9. Take advantage of the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function and write:

   ```
   Tsum = sum(d ** q for q, d in enumerate(digits, p))
   ```

Putting all this together:

```
def digit_power_multiplier(n,p):
    """Given a positive integer n with decimal digits a, b, c, d, ..., and
    a positive integer p, return k such that:

        a ** p + b ** (p+1) + c ** (p+2) + d ** (p+3) + ... = n * k

    If there is no such k, raise ValueError. For example:

        >>> digit_power_multiplier(695, 2)
        2

    since 6**2 + 9**3 + 5**4 = 1390 = 695 * 2.

    """
    lhs = sum(int(d) ** q for q, d in enumerate(str(n), p))
    if lhs % n == 0:
        return lhs // n
    else:
        raise ValueError("no k such that {} = {}*k".format(lhs, n))
```

Comment: Excellent answer as usual. Out of curiosity, any reason for using `zip`  and `count` instead of `enumerate` with a `start` value ?

I'd write `sum(int(d) ** p for p, d in enumerate(str(n), p))` for instance.

Comment: @Josay: I forgot about the second argument to `enumerate`!

Answer (score 2):

To make your code more pythonic we could modify the calculation of `LHS` in the following way:

```
''' calculate LHS '''
digits = [int(i) for i in list(str(n))]

tsum = 0
for i in digits:
    tsum += math.pow(i, p)
    p += 1
```

We use a list comprehension to build the `digits` list. The benefit being that later on when building up `tsum` we no longer have to call `reversed` on `digits`.

Comment: The call to `list` is not required. Also, you don't need to create the list `digits`, you just iterate over the string directly (or use a generator expression).